# Operador // no me retorna 0 al aplicarlo sobre un número par

Tags: python, condiciones

Estoy iniciándome en [python](/questions/tagged/python) y haciendo ejercicios de condicionales.

El ejercicio indica:

> Escribe un código que calcule el cuadrado de un número si este es impar, o el cubo de un número si este es par. Por ejemplo, para 4 tu programa debe entregar 64, y para 3 debe entregar 9.

Escribí el siguiente codigo:

```py
def exponenciacion(numero):
  resultado = numero
  if numero //2 == 0:
    numero = numero ** 3
  else:
     numero = numero ** 2
  resultado = numero
  return resultado
```

Pero en la corrección y también me he fijado en la consola si `numero = 22`, `numero` es elevado al cuadrado y no al cubo y no logro entender por qué.

Answer (score 4):

estás usando la división entera `//` en lugar de la división modular o de resto `%`
Si quieres saber si un número es par o divisible entre dos sería así
`n%2==0`

Answer (score 2):

Para saber si un número es par o no, debes aplicar el símbolo **"%"** en vez de "//". El símbolo "%" devuelve el resto de la división de los dos números (24%5==4) mientras que el símbolo "//" sirve para hacer la división entera de dos cifras **(5//2==2)**. Además, la variable resultado no aporta nada al código, así que se podría eliminar. Tu código quedaría así:

```
def exponenciacion(numero):
    if numero%2 == 0:
        return numero ** 3
    else:
       return numero ** 2
```

Te recomiendo mirar el uso de **lambda** ya que podrías reducir esa función a una sola línea, quedando tu código así:

```
exponenciacion=lambda numero: numero**3 if numero%2==0 else numero**2
```

Y para llamarlo se haría de la misma manera:

```
print(exponenciacion(3)) # Devuelve 9 -> 3**2 ya que 3%2 != 0
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Lo único que agregaría es explicar el propósito del operador `%` y por que es necesario hacer `== 0`.

Comment: Para el caso no es necesario una lambda: suficiente con `return numero**2 if numero%2 else numero**3`

Comment: Gracias @DanteS., ya he editado el código con esa incorporación

Comment: @aeportugal, creo que la implementación de lambda en este código no es necesaria (ya que se puede hacer de otras maneras, obviamente) pero es útil y mejora el código considerablemente. Además, nunca está de más añadir maneras diferentes para resolver problemas y creo que Maximiliano puede aprender sobre ello